# Algorithm for a turn-by-turn game?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm building a command line battle simulator. I have two teams: `redteam` and `blueteam`.

They have 4 features:

```
health
attack
defense
rep
```

First three are self-explanatory, I think. `rep` is reputation or fear factor. User will enter the features for both the teams. The team with the highest rep will start the attack first. `damage` = `attack - defense`. This is again subtracted from the `health`. Then the other team attacks, and the process continues until one of the team's `health <=0` or if the `attack <= defense` because in this case there'll be no damage done.

In this form, the game's pretty simple only the health changes and not anything else.

The question I have is I'm currently using arrays and a while loop inside which all the logic is placed in a bunch of nested `if-else` blocks. The code is really messy. Is there an algorithm (and datastructres) for this  kind of problem?

A

Comment: What do you mean by "specific kind of problem"? You already created an algorithm for your particular case.

Comment: By specific, I mean specific to turn-by-turn games.

Comment: I think that every turn-based game has something unique compared to others. The algorithm that works for most of them probably is: `while(true) { for(p : players) { p.take_turn(); if(p.won()) return; } }`

Comment: there r a lot of them! Read more about AI, expert systems, min/max trees, declarative libraries, AI libraries, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: IMHO better will be to use some library for such kind of games.

Comment: You could have a list of teams in a game, then do something like `for team in sorted(teams): team.take_turn()`

Comment: Go for `OOP` approach..it will save you from lots of problem regarding messy code.. For algorithm I guss previous comments say a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you have a bunch of nested if-else blocks. Let me know if I misunderstood the problem, otherwise have a look at this (^ means the XOR operation):

```
// Let the players be x[0] and x[1].

// Get the starting player.
int p = x[0].rep >= x[1].rep ? 0 : 1;

// Loop until the current player loses all its health.
while(x[p].health > 0 && x[p].attack > x[p^1].defense)
{
    // Player p makes an attack, and the
    // other player (p xor 1) takes damage.
    x[p^1].health -= x[p].attack - x[p^1].defense;

    // Switch to the other player.
    p ^= 1;
}

Print(Player p^1 wins);
```

Note that you could also use `1 - p` instead of `p ^ 1` to have the same functionality.